# CentOS Apache redirect

Tags: linux, apache, redirect, dns

Im trying to have an internal link points to a specific folder in my apache server
I've created a rule through my DNS server so that when a user goes to "vgr.intranet" it points to my apache server (192.168.1.62)

That being said, here's what I've done so far :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName http://vgr.intranet
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/vgr/
    Redirect permanent / http://192.168.1.62/vgr/
</VirtualHost>
```

So far all it does is it goes to the root of my apache server when it should go to that "/vgr/" folder.

Thanks.

Comment: You specified a URL as the ServerName, instead of the actual host name. It needs to be `ServerName vgr.intranet`

Comment: What is the point of that redirect supposed to be? If you already set up your DNS for that host name to resolve to this IP address, and the DocumentRoot is set to what is presumably the same directory, that `http://192.168.1.62/vgr/` would also access ... why redirect now?

Comment: Vgr.intranet is just a rule i've made in my DNS server so that it points to 192.168.1.62.. people will be browsing "http://vgr.intranet" as an URL into their browser instead of http://192.168.1.62/vgr

Comment: Basically to make this simple what im trying to accomplish is that vgr.intranet goes to 192.168.1.62/vgr. The rule i've setup into my windows server doesnt let me directly redirect to 192.168.1.62/vgr/ but only 192.168.1.62

Comment: Why would you need to redirect anywhere else, when you are explicitly setting up a VHost _for_ `vgr.intranet` here? You have your DNS set up to resolve that host name to the IP address, once you fixed your ServerName mistake Apache should "route" the request into that VHost - and then it will simply serve the content from the `DocumentRoot` you specified. So why _redirect_ now?

Comment: So you think that should do ? :

`ServerName vgr.intranet`
`DocumentRoot /var/www/html/vgr/`

Answer (score 1):

There may be another vgr directory in the root /var/www/html/vgr/ ?

If not, @CBroe is right the redirect is not useful because the vhost will load when you access vgr.intranet directly at the correct location.

Depending on what you want to do, document root and redirect should be consistent.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName vgr.intranet
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/vgr/
</VirtualHost>
```

OR

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName vgr.intranet
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    Redirect permanent / http://192.168.1.62/vgr/
</VirtualHost>
```